# How to add a counter to a list of identical elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, equals

Hey guys I am trying to create the following functions: If the next element in the array is greater than the previous add 1 to counter. However my problem is when I have identical elements. I want to add something that checks if all elements are identical add 1 to counter to every identical element. So in the example about [4,4,4,4,4] should output 5, since there are 5 elements that are identical

```js
function tower(arr) {
  //lave en counter for antallet af towers
  counter = 0
  counteridentical = 0
  //loop igennem listen
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //lave if statement og tjekke hvis næste er større, skal der countes +1
    if (arr[i]  < arr[(i + 1) % arr.length]) {
      counter++
    }
  }
  return counter
}
console.log(tower([4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3])) //expected output 3
console.log(tower([
  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
])) //expected output 5
```

Comment: your answer is not helping, since it doesn't take account for same elements.

Comment: no it should be 5, since there are 5 identical elements

Answer (score 0):

Your second array was nested

Here is my suggestion

```js
function tower(arr) {
  if (arr.every(val => val === arr[0])) return arr.length
  return arr.filter((val,i) => i === 0 || i > 0 && val > arr[i-1]).length 
  
}
console.log(tower([4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3])) //expected output 3
console.log(tower([ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ])) //expected output 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function tower(arr) {
  counter = 0
  counteridentical = 0
  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]  >= arr[(i - 1)]) {
      counter++
    }
  }
  return counter
}
```

Here is the logic:

1. Iterate from 2nd item to last item. i.e, for(let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++)
2. On every item, check if it is greater or equal to previous element
3. If step 2 returns true, increment the counter